# Ajax form not uploading file or sending emails

Tags: php, html, ajax

Before implementing AJAX the form was submitting, uploading the files and also sending the emails via PHP so I'm assuming there is some AJAX or PHP option that I'm missing. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

-

JQuery

```
    $('.form').submit(

        function(event) {

            var content = $(this).data('load'),
                url = $(this).attr('action');

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               processData: true,
               beforeSend: function() {

               },
               success: function(data) {    

                  $('.flex-inline').load(content, function() {

                     ajaxForms.init();

                  });           

               }
            });

            event.preventDefault();

    });
```

PHP

```
<?php

    $file_name = "video.mp4";

    $subject = 'X';
    $message = 'X';
    $headers = 'From: x@x.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: x@x.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();        

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["video"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {

        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

    } else {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $file_name)) {

            mail($_POST["email"], $subject, $message, $headers);

        }

}?>
```

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` generates a string. It can't include file data.

Comment: upload form by ajax you need to use formdata https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: mail function does not have uploaded file at all